# More user-friendly front end for using tasks in TFS

Tags: tfs

Compared with other task managing tools (especially web based ones) I find maintaining TFS' task system really uninspiring.

Are there any third party front ends for managing tasks through it?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/tfs). It is a great visual tool that offers two-way integration with TFS and a template scrum board.

Answer (score 2):

[Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com/) hands down.

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking of the Work Items, there are several front ends you can use. Out of the box, you have Visual Studio, Team Web Access, Microsoft Excel and Microsoft Project. But you can also take a look at tools like

- TeamCampanion (outlook integration): http://www.teamcompanion.com/OverviewVideo.htm
- TeamLook (outlook integration): http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamlook/download.aspx
- TeamSpec (word integration): http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec/teamspec-features.aspx

Comment: It is also very easy to write your own as TFS has one of the best API's.

Answer (score 1):

What problem do you have?

I find the interface provided within VS20xx to be sufficient.